# How to interpret thresholding functions plots

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

In the paper [The adaptive lasso and its oracle properties](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ezouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf), page 4, they show several images like these ones:

[image]

The caption of the image only states "Figure 1. Plot of Thresholding Functions". And my question is, precisely, that I do not know how to interpret these plots. ¿What is represented in the horizontal and the vertical axis? How do we go from (for example) the lasso formulation, as in this equation:

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(\text { lasso })=\underset{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{\arg \min }\left\|\mathbf{y}-\sum_{j=1}^{p} \mathbf{x}_{j} \beta_{j}\right\|^{2}+\lambda \sum_{j=1}^{p}\left|\beta_{j}\right|$$

To the associated plot, which is image (c)? And what is the interpretation of these plots?